# Searching Assets/Components via Nexus 3 programmatically

Tags: search, groovy, scripting, nexus3

Since the new version of Nexus has no more REST functionality to search the repositories for artifacts my idea is to use a Groovy script to build "my own REST" system.
Currently I am trying to post a script that looks like this:

```
@Singleton
class NexusSearch extends Script {
    @Inject
    SearchService service;

    def run() {
        assert service != null;
        return args;
    }
}
```

My problem is that service stays null and I don't know if injection would ever work in scripts. Is this the right approach? If yes what am I doing wrong, if not what would be the right approach?

Comment: This might help you in terms of what you want to accomplish: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41063108/using-the-nexus3-api-how-do-i-get-a-list-of-artifacts-in-a-repository/41070107#41070107

Comment: I'll try and get you an answer on your code separately

Comment: This is indeed very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking internally, you can't do injection directly in scripts, but you can use container.lookup(className)

Answer (score 0):

To come back to this and attempt to be future helpful, the REST API is now in beta, and you can give us some great feedback about it:

http://blog.sonatype.com/nexus-repository-new-beta-rest-api-for-content

Try this out now, given you were looking for it originally.