# Nexus - List Artifacts from repository

Tags: rest, artifacts, nexus3

Is there any way to list artifact in Nexus v3.0, other that using rest API? 
As the rest API for this version have not been implemented yet.

Comment: This might help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41063108/using-the-nexus3-api-how-do-i-get-a-list-of-artifacts-in-a-repository/41070107#41070107

Comment: @DarthHater but this will require groovy to be on machine right ? And that will be pre-requistie.

Answer (score 1):

At this time, the REST API has been released as beta. You can get more information and give us feedback by going to this link: http://blog.sonatype.com/nexus-repository-new-beta-rest-api-for-content

It should address this use case, as well!