# Setup custom cleanup for docker images in nexus repository

Tags: docker, groovy, nexus

I've been handling docker images stored in our nexus repository by using [cleanup policies](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/repository-management/cleanup-policies). these are good for basic behavior, configured in the tasks that run daily (or hourly or w.e you want) like so:

1. first task will be of type **Admin - Cleanup repositories using their associated policies**
2. 2nd of type **Docker - Delete unused manifests and images**
3. 3rd of type **Admin - Compact blob store**

The cleanup policy has a regex, to avoid deleting a certain image tagged in a certain way (**eg:** build-latest), and a last downloaded at (**eg:** 5 days).

Now this helps deleting images every X days but some images needed to be kept as long as no other exist, i.e if the only image that exist is **build-99** do not delete it, which is something I couldn't do with only policies.

how the repo looks like for what I want to achieve:

[image: repo example]

`my-repository` is just a folder name that by default takes the repository name, its just to demonstrate.

so how do you manage this ?

**note:** information specified on what was done here can be found in different SO posts or github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a groovy script that is run automatically everyday I was able to do this.
The script is set in a task of **Admin - Execute script** which is disabled by default in nexus newer version, which I solved following [Scripting Nexus Repository Manager 3](https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/360045220393-Scripting-Nexus-Repository-Manager-3) in the FAQ Section, aswell as [How to Determine the Location of the Nexus 3 Data Directory](https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/218707647).

The script is based on documentation, issues, and code from different places (**eg:** [StorageTxImpl.java](https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-public/blob/master/components/nexus-repository/src/main/java/org/sonatype/nexus/repository/storage/StorageTxImpl.java) is where you can find methods that fetch/delete assets, components, etc). It was inspired by these aswell
[Using the Nexus3 API how do I get a list of artifacts in a repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41063108/using-the-nexus3-api-how-do-i-get-a-list-of-artifacts-in-a-repository), [NEXUS-14837](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-14837) and [Nexus 3 Groovy Script development environment setup](https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/115015812727-Nexus-3-Groovy-Script-development-environment-setup)

The script:

The script must be run before the second task (i.e equal to the first, before or after doesn't matter). the policies were also no longer needed so they were no longer assigned to the repository.

how it works or what it does:

- fetch the repository
- fetch the components of a repo
- group them by name (**eg:** repository/my-repository/some-project/service-A)
- for each service loop its components and get their assets
- filter the assets by their `last_downloaded` and keep only the ones not matching the most recent 3 for eg
- delete the components related to the assets (nexus `deleteComponent(cp)` internally deletes the assets and their blobs)

**note:** I saw scripts can be parameterized but it was not needed in my case

**note:** this can be updated to loop all repositories but I just needed one

```
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.Asset
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.Query
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.StorageFacet

import groovy.json.JsonOutput
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.Repository

class RepositoryProcessor {
    private final log
    private final repository
    private final String repoName = 'my-repository'
    private final String[] ignoreVersions = ['build-latest']
    private final int processIfSizeGt = 3
    private final int delAllButMostRecentNImages = 2

    RepositoryProcessor(log, repository) {
        this.log = log
        this.repository = repository
    }

    void processRepository() {
        def repo = repository.repositoryManager.get(repoName)
        log.debug("found repository: {}", repo)
        // will use default of sonatype
        // https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-public/blob/master/components/nexus-repository/src/main/java/org/sonatype/nexus/repository/storage/StorageFacetImpl.java
        StorageFacet storageFacet = repo.facet(StorageFacet)
        log.debug("initiated storage facet: {}", storageFacet.toString())
        // tx of type https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-public/blob/master/components/nexus-repository/src/main/java/org/sonatype/nexus/repository/storage/StorageTxImpl.java $$EnhancerByGuice ??
        def transaction = storageFacet.txSupplier().get()
        log.debug("initiated transaction instance: {}", transaction.toString())

        try {
            transaction.begin()

            log.info("asset count {}", transaction.countAssets(Query.builder().build(), [repo]))
            log.info("components count {}", transaction.countComponents(Query.builder().build(), [repo]))

            // queried db is orientdb, syntax is adapted to it
            def components = transaction.findComponents(Query.builder()
                    // .where("NOT (name LIKE '%service-A%')")
                    // .and("NOT (name LIKE '%service-B%')")
                    .build(), [repo])
            // cp and cpt refers to component
            // group by name eg: repository/my-repository/some-project/service-A
            def groupedCps = components.groupBy{ it.name() }.collect()

            // fetch assets for each cp
            // and set them in maps to delete the old ones
            groupedCps.each{ cpEntry ->
                // process only if its greater than the minimum amount of images per service
                if (cpEntry.value.size > processIfSizeGt) {
                    // single component processing (i.e this would be done for each service)
                    def cpMap = [:] // map with key eq id
                    def cpAssetsMap = [:] // map of cp assets where key eq cp id
                    // process service cpts
                    cpEntry.value.each { cp ->
                        // cp id of type https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-public/blob/master/components/nexus-orient/src/main/java/org/sonatype/nexus/orient/entity/AttachedEntityId.java
                        def cpId = cp.entityMetadata.id.identity
                        // asset of type: https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-public/blob/master/components/nexus-repository/src/main/java/org/sonatype/nexus/repository/storage/Asset.java
                        def cpAssets = transaction.browseAssets(cp).collect()
                       
                        // document of type https://github.com/joansmith1/orientdb/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/orientechnologies/orient/core/record/impl/ODocument.java
                        // _fields of type: https://github.com/joansmith1/orientdb/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/orientechnologies/orient/core/record/impl/ODocumentEntry.java
                        // any field is of type ODocumentEntry.java
                        // append to map if it does not belong to the ignored versions
                        if (!(cp.entityMetadata.document._fields.version.value in ignoreVersions)) {
                            cpMap.put(cpId, cp)
                            cpAssetsMap.put(cpId, cpAssets)
                        }
                    }
                    // log info about the affected folder/service
                    log.info("cp map size: {}, versions: {}",
                            cpMap.values().size(),
                            cpMap.values().entityMetadata.document._fields.version.value)
                    // order desc by last_downloaded (default is asc)
                    log.debug("cp map assets of size: {}", cpAssetsMap.values().size())
                    def sortedFilteredList = cpAssetsMap.values()
                            .sort { it.entityMetadata.document._fields.last_downloaded?.value }
                            .reverse(true)
                            .drop(delAllButMostRecentNImages)
                    // list of cp ids from the assets that going to be deleted
                    def sortedAssetsCps = sortedFilteredList.entityMetadata.document._fields.component?.value?.flatten()
                    log.info("cp map assets size after filtering {}", sortedFilteredList.size())
                    // this will print the cps ids to delete
                    log.debug("elements to delete : sorted assets cps list {}", sortedAssetsCps)
                    // deleting components and their assets
                    cpMap.findAll { it.key in sortedAssetsCps }
                            .each { entry ->
                                log.info("deleting cp version {}", entry.value.entityMetadata.document._fields.version?.value)
                                // this will call delete asset internally, and by default will delete blob
                                transaction.deleteComponent(entry.value)
                            }
                }
            }
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.warn("transaction failed {}", e.toString())
            transaction.rollback()
        } finally {
            transaction.close();
        }
    }
}

new RepositoryProcessor(log, repository).processRepository()
```

Comment: Sometimes it deletes wrong assets because of a strange sorting. For example i've seen today a list was sorted by the dates in this order:


Fri Apr 14 11:35:27 UTC 2023
Wed Feb 22 11:47:01 UTC 2023
Wed Feb 22 11:45:44 UTC 2023
Wed Feb 22 11:17:09 UTC 2023
Mon Apr 24 15:57:04 UTC 2023